# Java - How to create argument in method that will accept classes that are A.class or extends A.class?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

How to create argument in method that will accept A.class or extends A.class?

I am creating method that will execute method "foe()" in A.class.

This is why I need argument that will be A.class or that will extend A.class.

```
class B extends A{}
//And
abstract class A{}
```

This does not work for A.class, but works for B.class:

```
public void test(Class<? extends A> arg){}
```

This, ofc, works only for A.class, but not for B.class:

```
public void test(A arg){}
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Is it me? I have no idea what you're problem is or what you're asking. Are you wanting A and B objects passed into your method or A and B Classes? This question looks to be an unclear [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question, and you'll want to both tell us more about your overall problem as well as show concrete **real** code, not kind-of sort-of code.

Comment: The middle code snippet does not compile, the third code snippet does exactly what you want, you can pass in A or B instances.  Alternatively the second one should work after you replace the `)` with a `>`.

Comment: I want an argument in my method that will accept A.class and B.class, like test(<Class that is A or extend A> arg){}

Comment: @luk2302: the 3rd snippet doesn't work with `A.class` or `B.class`.

Comment: But again, let's avoid a frustrating [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) wild goose chase. Please explain the over-all problem, and please show *real* code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well, yes, that does not work, but I am still not sure if he talking about passing actual class references or instances of those classes. What I meant was the 3rd works for instance of the classes, the 2nd works for `Class<>` instances.

Comment: Are you assuming your code snippets do not work? Or have you actually tested them?

Comment: @luk2302: exactly the point of my first comment. The whole thing is very confusing, and we would all benefit greatly if he could make things much more concrete.

Comment: Ignore this examples.. It is really simple - How to write argument in method that will be compilable with usage of A.class or B.class that extends A.class. Example usage of this method: test(A arg), test(B arg).

Comment: If you are asking about passing in the class reference the first code snippet works. If you are asking about passing into instances of those classes the second code snippet works. Please show what you are actually trying to do, show some sample invocations of `test` that you want to work.

Comment: @PiotrOsada you keep using an extremely wrong terminology. `A a = new A();`: that defines a variable `a` which is an instance of A. You can pass `a` to a method `foo(A a)`. You can also pass `b` to that method if `b` is defined with `B b = new B();`, since B extends A, and `b` is thus an instance of `A`. You **cannot** pass A.class, nor B.class, because A.class is an instance (the unique instance) of Class<A>. The type Class<A> and the type A are radically different things. There is no such thing as "extending A.class", since A.class is not a type. It's an object.

Comment: @luk2302 sorry, this was meant to be addressed to the OP, not to you.

Comment: test(ArrayList<CLASSARGUMENT>); Yeah, I see - with simple class type it works, my examples were bad :x. Look with ArrayList please

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for explain. I am newbie and I am sorry for this mistakes :P

Comment: Use [edit] to provide ACTUAL examples that should run, ***please***.

Answer (score 2):

Last effort on getting this to you:
You have the following options for now.

```
public void testClass(Class<? extends A> arg) {}
public void testInstance(A arg) {}

...

testInstance(new A()); // works    
testInstance(new B()); // works

testClass(A.class); // works
testClass(B.class); // works
```

Last but not least you can use generics:

```
public <T extends A> void testInstanceGen(T arg) {}
public <T extends A> void testClassGen(Class<T> arg) {}

...

testInstanceGen(new A()); // works    
testInstanceGen(new B()); // works

testClassGen(A.class); // works
testClassGen(B.class); // works
```

*I will happily delete this as soon as the difference in functionality of the different methods becomes clear to OP - for now this is posted because it exceeds a comment.*

Comment: I have to up-vote this because it does answer all the (confusing) questions that the OP has posted so far, and I appreciate your efforts in this very frustrating endeavor.

Comment: Unfortunately, It seems the OP actually wants a method that accepts a List<A> and a List<B>. Replacing Class<...> by List<...> answers his question.